# Assign value to instance of current class

Tags: vb.net

I have a class we will call MyClass.  Inside I have some deserialization code that I want to be able to call from within the object.   Is there a cleaner way to assign the values associated with the class from within the class.
Here is what I am doing now

```
Public Class MyClass
  Public Property Prop1 as New String(String.empty)
  Public Property Prop2 as New String(String.empty)
  Public Property Prop3 as Boolean = False
  Public Sub LoadXML(ByVal XMLText as String)
     Dim MyTemp as New MyClass
     MyTemp = CType(DeSerialize(XMLText, MyTemp.Type), MyClass)  'this returns an object
     Me.Prop1 = MyTemp.Prop1
     Me.Prop2 = MyTemp.Prop2
     Me.Prop3 = MyTemp.Prop3
  End Sub 
End Class
```

I cannot assign the result of **MyTemp** to **Me** (which ostensibly represent the same object type) but I can assign all of the *properties* of **MyTemp** to the *properties* of **Me**.   Since my actual class is much more complicated (I used primitives in the example - but in reality is a pretty large class with properties that are many other classes) I wondered if there is a better way to assign the value of **MyTemp** to the instance of the class.

Comment: Whats the point of `MyTemp`? Since the XML already represents a MyClass object, why not just create it directly rather than hopscotch thru a temp object property by property?

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm not sure what you mean by "...the XML already represents a MyClass object..." - the XML is a String type that gets passed into the LoadXML sub.   The purposed of the MyTemp is to create an object that is the equivalent of Me.   Since you cannot do something like: 'Me = CType(DeSerialize(XMLText, Me.Type), MyClass)' - I'm forced to create the temp and then hopscotch through the top-level properties.  It does look silly but that's why I raised this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create a Shared function that will return an instance of MyClass in lieu of a constructor.

```
Public Shared Function LoadXML(ByVal XMLText As String) As MyClass1
    Dim MyTemp As New MyClass1
    MyTemp = CType(DeSerialize(XMLText, MyTemp.GetType()), MyClass1)
    Return MyTemp
End Function
```

You can run this to create the initial instance of the class, so instead of calling new you would call MyClass.LoadXML(xmlString).

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be a lot better off to declare `LoadXML` as a `shared` function that just returned the deserialized object.  That way, instead of

```
dim myClassInstance = new MyClass();
myClassInstance.LoadXML(...)
```

You would do

```
dim myClassInstance = MyClass.LoadXML(...);
```

And you wouldn't need to do all that property copying.

(sorry, VB is rusty)